# Using MVC Profiler for the first time. Performance issues + Query Timeouts

Tags: model-view-controller, timeout, profiler, mvc-mini-profiler

We have a mixed .NET & open source (django, python, perl, php, etc.) environment and lately we've been getting query timeouts.  I ran across this tool from Brent Ozar's webcast on scaling at stack overflow.

I can't wait to use it to see why some of our pages are super slow, and if it's on the DB side but does anyone have any recommendations on how to troubleshoot timeout errors using MVC profiler and is there a 'MVC Profiler for non programers' link I can read?  I wanted to get very familiar with it but I am a DBA and haven't found too many resources that I can understand.

Mostly I'm concerned with:
-How to reduce the impact to production.  I know this tool was designed specifcially to minimize production impact but what are the risks?

-How granular can I get?  I probably can't pull out MS SQL Server info such as how long each query took and the execution plan for each, which I'm ok with.

-Once it's 'setup', can I myself just test the site from my browser, send some kind of a link to my co-workers and have them set it up?

Thanks in advance.

Thank you!

Comment: Just to help anyone else out there, we weren't able to use the mini-profiler.  What I did was use a tiny vm for a web server that only I know of, and then use our site from that webserver.  Doing that I was able to profile SQL Server activity filtered by host.